# Why is there no analytic antiderivative of a multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I've been working through (with [some help](http://www.weylmann.com/gaussian.pdf)) the standard formulae for multivariate Gaussians.  But I can't find anything on analytic formulae (even with error functions) for the antiderivatives. Why not?

To qualify why expect that there should be an antiderivative, I worked as follows.  The probability density function is

\begin{align}
P&=N\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}\right)\right]
\end{align}

where $N$ is the normalization constant. I want to integrate over each of $n$ dimensions from $0$ to $z_n$. Let $S^{-1}AS=D$ be a (the?) diagonalization of $A$, such that $S$ is unitary ($S^T=S^{-1}$) and $D$ is diagonal, with elements $d_i$. And let $Sx=y$. (I think that's everything I need...)

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{z_1}\cdots\int_0^{z_n}N
  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}\right)\right]
  dx_1\ldots dx_n \\
&=\int_0^{z_1}\cdots\int_0^{z_n}N
  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{x}^TA\vec{x}\right)\right]
  dx_1\ldots dx_n \\
&=\int_0^{z_1}\cdots\int_0^{z_n}N
  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{x}^TS^TDS\vec{x}\right)\right]
  dx_1\ldots dx_n \\
&=\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_1}\cdots\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_n}N
  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\vec{y}^TD\vec{y}\right)\right]
  |S|dy_1\ldots dy_n \\
&=\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_1}\cdots\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_n}N
  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^nd_iy_i^2\right]
  dy_1\ldots dy_n \\
&=N\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_1}e^{-\frac{1}{2}d_1y_1^2}dy_1
  \ldots\int_0^{(S\vec{z})_n}e^{-\frac{1}{2}d_ny_n^2}dy_n
\end{align}
The last integrals can all be expressed in terms of error functions. Why is this wrong?

It's been some years since I last studied maths in detail, so I apologize for abuses of notation and other errors. Let me know what needs clarification or correction.

Comment: Consider dimension $2$, since that's easy to visualize. When you apply the rotation $S$ to a rectangular region $0 \leqslant x \leqslant c,\, 0 \leqslant y \leqslant d$, you get a rectangle that is not bounded by axis-parallel lines, so your region of integration becomes a bit more complicated.

Comment: @DanielFischer, sorry for leaving this so long, but if you make that an answer I'll accept. I did read this and then look into it, I clearly forgot to come back and respond!